# What is the maximal number of edges of a graph on n vertices that does not contain a path with m edges.

Tags: graph-theory

My attempt:Let G be a graph were V(G)=n and $V_{max}(G)$ is the value we are looking for. We dont want G to contain any path with m edges, so if there is a path with m edges then there must be at least m edges in the graph. Therefore let G be a union of two disjunct components, A and B, such that $A \cup B=G$ and $A \cap B= \emptyset$. Let $E(A)=a=m-1<m.$ Then what value can E(B) have?

Construct the smallest trail in $A$, then $V(A)=a-1=m-2.$ Then $V(B)=n-(m-2)=n-m+2$ vertices. We now want to maximize $n.$ And now I don't know how to get further?

Comment: Why just two components? If $m=2$ then the maximal number of edges should be obtained by partitioning the vertex set into pairs and connecting the pairs with single edges (of which there will be $\lfloor V/2\rfloor$). Maybe start by considering the maximal number of edges in any connected component of $G$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by maximizing $n$.  Aren't $n$ and $m$ given?

Comment: Okay so there can be a lot of components, the maximal number of edges in any connected component of G: if every vertex has maximum degree?

Comment: When you say "path" here, what restrictions are you putting on it? For instance, if paths are allowed to reverse course, then the obvious answer would be $0$, regardless of $n, m$. Can your paths ever cross the same edge twice? In that case, loops are forbidden. But if you are counting only paths through distinct edges, they are not.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I think my teacher means paths through distinct edges

Comment: Then (barring other unmentioned restrictions) the answer would $n(m-1)$. Put $m-1$ loops on each vertex. Adding one more edge anywhere will allow a path passing through $m$ edges. (That only shows $n(m-1)$ is local maximum - all allowable small changes to the graph decreases the number edges, but I have little doubt it is the full maximum.) I put the qualification on, though, because it isn't that interesting of an answer, so I suspect this isn't the intended meaning.